# Staging backend for e2e frontend testing

Tags: node.js, angular, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

We are using angular at frontend and Node.js at backend.

We are writing e2e tests at frontend and as I understand it should use real backend. So we have staging environment and Angular app e2e tests are using real Node.js staging backend there. Staging backend use staging database and staging log environment.

Questions:

1. Is it okay to use real staging backend for e2e frontend testing?
2. How to be with reset password testing, where we need JWT which is generated at backend and then sent to email? Should I hardcode some token for some special test user?
3. What about making e2e tests without real backend? Is it weird?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to use real staging backend for e2e frontend testing?

It's preferable to set up test web server and database that don't have any other uses to avoid cross-contamination. Otherwise tests may ruin real environment, while real environment may affect test results. It's a good practice to run test environment in a container for this reason.

> How to be with reset password testing, where we need JWT which is generated at backend and then sent to email? Should I hardcode some token for some special test user?

Hard-coded token may work but it will prevent this feature from being tested. To test it more thoroughly, mail server or a library that uses it (e.g. [`nodemailer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-stub-transport)) can be mocked in testing environment.

> What about making e2e tests without real backend? Is it weird?

This makes them integration tests, they are valid ways to test an application. Frontend and backend integration tests can provide full coverage, in theory. But inconsistencies between them can result in malfunctioning application while all tests are passing. In addition to integration tests, minimal E2E test coverage may still be beneficial. Depending on the case, it may be limited to read-only operations and use real web server.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a staging real backend to test that your frontend works with your backend. Your test user should be a regular user. You're free test as much as you want, as far as testing a password reset it's up to you to e2e test that in particular. You can do it, you can have the test wait to receive an email and follow links to reset and so on it's up to you whether you're comfortable with your app deployed to production with this feature potentially broken